# (beginner) C# / WCF: Socket connection aborted

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, net.tcp

I'm creating an application for manage stock from a distance for Windows, in C#.

My client-server communication works, I can exchange some String, bool, int, etc. But I can't get DataTable or other kind of objects from the server. Currently I do my tests with few data in my database, the server managed to read the data when client call the function but the client doesn't recieve the function return (a DataTable).

This is my error message:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.2590000'.

My host:

```
NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
netTcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 10000000;
netTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000000;
netTcpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
netTcpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceWCF));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISLM_serviceContract),
                    netTcpBinding,"net.tcp://localhost:10108/SLM_WCF");
host.Open();
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add some code, how you construct and return `DataTable` in `WCF` service, and also your client code that makes call to `WCF` service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using `DataTable`. Yes, really: they are a pain to use, so why bother? And in top of that, you loose strong typing.

More seriously, this is caused by the fact that WCF needs to know beforehand the format on your message, and loosely typed values won't do with the default serializer (`DataContractSerializer`).

So you may either switch the serializer to `NetDataContractSerializer`, which should be able to handle this kind of scenario (I never tested it with `DataTable` but I suppose it could work).

Or the better solution: create an object of your own (strongly typed), that represents a *row* and return a list of that.

Answer (score 1):

While I strongly agree with @Lucas point, to avoid using `DataTable` whenever you can in `WCF`, I would suggest a possible solution to the problem, in case you have to use `DataTable` for some reasons. 
Since you setup `TimeOut` and `MessageSize` to really big numbers, I would suspect this is actually a problem with serialization of the message. In particular, you will have this problem if you do not set the name of the `DataTable` when creating it.

```
public DataTable MyServiceMethod()
{
   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
   // populate dataTable;
   return dataTable;
}
```

If this is how you're creating data table, it might fail to serialize, instead you need to give a name to the `dataTable`

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("myDataTable);
```